# Set color to string programatically in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview

I have bunds of strings to load into listview what i need to set text color to string

I google lot but i got only

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

im not using textview i juz load strings directly into listview

Somebody suggested to do the follow

```
String s="Hello World";
SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(s);                
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, 5, 0);
```

but its not working for me

pls any suggestion Thanx in advance

Comment: are you using a adapter something like this?...new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);

Comment: You are using a TextView. There is no way to 'just load strings directly' into a listview.

Comment: then how do you load the string?

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(" <font color='red'>");
sb.append("Hello World");
sb.append("</font>");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The code below set the text in the `TextView` to `"Hello World"` where `"Hello"` is red and `"World"` is green.

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
SpannableString myStr1 = new SpannableString("Hello");
SpannableString myStr2 = new SpannableString("World");
myStr1.setSpan( new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, myStr1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
myStr2.setSpan( new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, myStr2.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
myTextView.setText(TextUtils.concat(myStr1, " ", myStr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to change the color of textview text means use like this

```
     textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#123123")); // give your own text color here
```

It will work.